Can black holes exchange Hawking radiation, avoiding complete evaporation?
I was wondering if it would be possible that, as a black hole radiates its mass as Hawking radiation, another black hole could absorb that radiation and then when the second black hole radiates its mass the first one could absorb it as well, maintaining an equilibrium that would result in a net zero loss of mass for both black holes.
However, Hawking radiation is emitted in all directions, so we would need infinite black holes around each one of them to make sure that radiation does not escape. This would obviously be impossible
Then, is there any way in which this could be achieved? Any way in which the Hawking radiation could be directed towards another black hole?
Perhaps, if two black holes existed as a binary, the gravity of one black hole would attract all the radiation from the other one (and vice versa)?
Or perhaps if two black holes became entangled (https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.14596) they would exchange Hawking radiation avoiding complete evaporation?
Or alternatively, if there was some type of black hole that would radiate only massive particles instead of photons, they wouldn't escape the gravitational pull so easily (especially if they are emitted at relatively low velocities) and could be re-absorbed into the black hole?
Any ideas?...

If you add Olber's Paradox to your first thought, you might be onto something. Eventually many stars will collapse into black holes. Eventually matter that didn't collapse will fall into a black hole. Eventually enough time will have passed that Hawking radiation will reach a black hole if there is one in the direction it is traveling. This leads to questions of the expansion of space and the ultimate density of black holes.

Just as a small comment this depends on the exact background and model you are looking at (which I guess should be something close to our universe in your case). However generally what you say can be achieved even with a single black hole. If you look at a space akin to AdS Hawking radiation (If one uses reflecting boundary conditions) will fall back to where it came from so nothing ever changes.

@ThomasTappeiner and would there be any possibility in a dS spacetime like our universe is approaching into?

Note that astrophysical black holes are currently cooler than the cosmic microwave background, and will therefore be net absorbers of radiation for quite some time into the future.

@rob yes but I'm considering a scenario where the CMB is completely redshifted
